# how can i change visibility of menuitem from another activity?

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse

can anybody tell me how to change the visibility of a menuitem from another activity?
I have two activities "activity A and B". in one activity A when I press a menu item it saves some strings to the list of activity B and In activity A menuitem visibility set to false. now I want that when I delete that item from activity B which I saved from activity A, with this delete the menuitem visibility in activity A changes to true and it become visible again? so how can I do this. I using database to populate listview.

Activity A

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.atherosclerosis, menu);


        return true;
    }


    // for starting activity from the option or menu//
      @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


          SharedPreferences myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
          final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
          favClicked = myPrefs.getBoolean("menu_item", false);



          switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.id_favorit:
// Add it to the DB and re-draw the ListView
                myDb.insertRow("Atherosclerosis", 0, "");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Added to favorite list!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                favClicked=true;
                editor.putBoolean("menu_item", favClicked);
                editor.commit();
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;

            case R.id.id_favorit2:
                myDb.deleteRow("Atherosclerosis");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item deleted from favorite list!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                favClicked=false;
                editor.putBoolean("menu_item", favClicked);
                editor.commit();
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
            }
        return true;
        }
           @Override
            public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


         if(favClicked==true){
               menu.findItem(R.id.id_favorit).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.id_favorit2).setVisible(true);

         }else{
           menu.findItem(R.id.id_favorit).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.id_favorit2).setVisible(false);

     }
```

Activity B

```
private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

        // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
        // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
                {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.KEY_STUDENTNUM};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                {R.id.item_name};

        // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        this,       // Context
                        R.layout.item_layout,   // Row layout template
                        cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                        fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                        toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                        );

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favlistView1);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }

    private void registerListClickCallback() {
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favlistView1);



        //This code is for to delete the single item from the listview of favorite list
        myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, final long arg3) {
                Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(arg3);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


                        new AlertDialog.Builder(FavoriteDiseases.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete Item")
                        .setMessage("Do you want to delete this disease?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                // continue with delete
                                myDb.deleteItem(arg3);
                                populateListViewFromDB();
                        }
                     })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                            // do nothing
                        }
                     })
                     .show();            
    }
                return true;

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a little more context for a good answer how are the activities related is one calling the other?

But in general if activity a is calling activity b. Then you could just call startActivityForResult when starting activity b. When b is finished return a status that informs activity a that the item has been deleted.

To update the menu assuming you are creating your menu by overriding onCreateOptionsMenu, then just have that method check a flag to set a state of the menu item. Then in your onActivityResult method set the flag based on the result of activity b and call invalidateOptionsMenu() which will redraw your options menu.